# 2 way anova or mixed design anova?

Tags: anova, experiment-design, two-way

I am a Performance psychology student and previously have very little experience with statistics.
I gave an 8 week intervention to 15 students. They were tested 3 times, pre course, mid course and post with 3 different questionnaires, wb , Ders and Maas.
I also have a control group of 10 who were tested also 3 times with the same 3 questionnaires but they had No intervention.

So far I've got all the data in Spss and completed basic descriptive statistics for the 3 times points for each questionnaire, and each group (experimental and control) and completed a repeated anova for each variable to find if I had any statistically significant results. I did for ders and wb but not Maas.

1. Can some one please confirm whether next I need to perform a 2 way repeated measures anova or mixed design repeated measures anova? Or I saw from my reading perhaps a 2x 3 anova (2 groups but 3 time points) but I don't know if this is mixed design or not?
2. I am aware this is very basic but in my research can I confirm my iv =intervention/control. Dv=Maas/ders/wb my within subjects factor is =time (pre, mid, post) and 3 questionnaires (Maas dears wb) and between subjects factor = intervention /control.

Any help greatly appreciated very stuck and feel I can't move forward with analysis until I know the above!